# git creates merge commit instead of using fast forward. Why?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I am working on a WebApp project that uses a bare git repository that is organizes in three branches:

1. dev-master
2. beta-master
3. public-master

All development is done using a clone of the `dev-master` branch: Not the complete repository was cloned but only the specific branch:

```
git clone /path/to/bare/repo.git --branch dev-master dev
```

Once a new feature is ready, the changes in `dev-master` are `pushed` to the bare repo:

```
// Within dev repository
git push
```

The changes are then first published in a beta version of the WebApp. This is just another clone of the bare repo. This time of course a clone of the `beta-master` branch.

**What is the correct/right strategy to copy the changes from `dev-master` to `beta-master`?**

```
cd path/to/beta/
git fetch
git merge origin/dev-master
```

Once the features have been tested, I would do the same to get the changes from beta to public,

This works, but has one downside: Each time this is done, git creates a merge commit in `beta-master` instead of simply using fast forward. This does not make the history easier to read...

So, what would be correct workflow in a situation like this?

Comment: At the bare minimum, having the merge commit gives you a spot to potentially revert the merge in case things go awry.